# PHP MVC Operator Comparison

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Objective : If the database returns the number 1 , then it redirects to setup page, if it returns 2  , its redirect to setup page 2 if it returns 0 then it activates else statement

I have been trying this out for awhile but still seem to get it to work
My Controller :

```
    $user_id                 = array('id'=>$this->loggedInUser->id);
    $results                 = $this->user_model->getUsersStage($user_id);

    if($results == '1'){
    redirect('registration/setup');
    }
```

My Model :

```
 function getUsersStage($conditions=array(),$fields='')
 {

    if(count($conditions)>0)        
        $this->db->where($conditions);

    $this->db->from('users');

    if($fields!=''){
    $this->db->select($fields);
    }
    else{
    $this->db->select('stage');
    }


    $result = $this->db->get();
    return $result;


 }//End of getUsersStage Function
```

Would be nice if you could let me know what went wrong, I tried lots of comparison method , like

```
if($results == 1){  
Error : Object of class CI_DB_mysql_result could not be converted to int
if(this->$results->stage == 1)
```

just to verify, `$this->loggedInUser` is working and it does send the correct sql statement to the model.

Comment: What you are doing basically. let us know the functionality so we can see where you are doing wrong. Explain it briefly

Comment: Have you tried `$results->result()->stage`?

Comment: @Stanley Yap, Undefined property: CI_DB_mysql_result::$stage

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
if($results == '1'){
    redirect('registration/setup');
    }
```

to

```
if($results->row()->stage == 1){
    redirect('registration/setup');
    }
```

Comment: i saw that you are a LAMP developer , i tried bitnami and one of the linux admin told me that it isnt good, any suggestions? i'm using amazon ec2 :) I need to host my codeigniter php APP :)

Answer (score 2):

[$this->db->get()](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html) returns the result set.

```
 $query = $this->db->get('mytable');
 // Produces: SELECT * FROM mytable
```

If you want to check whether the it returns the rows or not you can check some thing like this

```
if(count($result->result())) {

  // do stuff here
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Aftec calling get() – [one of the active record functions](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html), you get a query object. You need to call [methods of that object](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/results.html) to actually get results. You will probably want to call `row()` on your result object, like:

```
if($results->row()->staging == 1)
```